# Cómo saber si un registro ya existe en la BD sql developer?

Tags: java, oracle, netbeans, oracle-sqldeveloper

mi pregunta ya la he formulado en el título, la cuestión está en que, cuando de click en el botón de guardar me verifique si ese registro existe en la base de datos (trabajo con **SQL developer**, **Netbeans**), y quiero que lo haga en tiempo real, he investigado pero nada.

Mi código de guardar esta full, la conexión full, lo único sería que me validara los datos ingresados.

Comment: y como sabes si existe? preguntando si existe. por favor mira [ask] para mejorar la pregunta. Deberías decirnos que has probado hasta ahora.

Comment: SQL Developer no es una base de datos, es una herramienta que permite conectarse a una base de datos y ejecutar sentencias. Fuera de eso, si quieres revisar si un registro existe, ejecuta una sentencia `SELECT`

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo muy bien que respuesta quieres, pero te recomiendo que te veas un tutorial básico de SQL de las consultas SELECT con WHERE

Aquí te dejo como sería un ejemplo:

```
SELECT NOMBRE, APELLIDOS, DNI 
FROM TABLA_CLIENTES
WHERE DNI = 'parametro_enrtada';
```

Si estas trabajando con una base de datos Oracle, te recomiendo usar el JDeveloper ya que con el puedes crear llamadas a la base de datos con "un par de clicks" *(si eliges esta opción y tienes dudas, puedes contestarme y gustosamente te ayudaré con ello)* y además es bastante mas seguro que poner tu las consultas SQL a mano creando la conexión.

Answer (score -1):

Subscribo lo que han dicho mas arriba, pero como veo que trabajas con netbeans te dejo una funcion para comprobar lo que tu dices, que compruebe si existe algo (en el ejemplo un codigo) en la DB, si da resultados la consulta quiere decir que el elemento esta duplicado, aplicalo a todos los campos que quieras comprobar.

```
function testCode()
{
    //debug_to_console("Inside php testCode function");
    $code = $_POST['code'];
    //debug_to_console("Recibido:$code");

    $conn = connectDB(); 

    $sql = "SELECT code FROM tabla WHERE code=$code";

    //debug_to_console("query:$sql");
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);

    if($result){
        if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
        //debug_to_console("result: $result");
            $valor = mysql_result($result, 0);
        }else{
            $valor = "no";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $valor = "no";
    }
    //debug_to_console("valor: $valor");

    echo json_encode(array('valor' => $valor));

    mysql_close($conn);    
}
```

Te dejo tambien la funcion de conexion

```
function connectDB () {
    $db = parse_ini_file("../ini/configuration.ini");
    $conn = mysql_connect($db['hostdb'], $db['user'], $db['pass']);
    if (!$conn) {
        debug_to_console("Error selectDB");
        die(mysql_error());
    }
    else
    {
        // Don't uncomment this, problems with json.
        //debug_to_console("Succesful connection");
    }
    mysql_select_db($db['dbname']);
    mysql_set_charset('utf8');

    return $conn;
}
```

Comment: La pregunta es en Java y el código puesto aquí está en PHP...